# Passing parameter to crystal report and link it to database fields to get specific record and show it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, .net-4.0, reportparameter

I have build crystal report with vs 2013 and I did the following

1. add the database fields for the tables I need.
2. I am calling the report from `form1` and it display the data

so it is good but what I need to is

get an `ID` from `textbox` in the `form1` and pass it as parameter to report 
so it display a specific record from database fields, so I made a parameter called `P_PatientID` and pass it to report below is the code I am using on `form_load` to call the `crystal report` and pass the parameter `P_PatientID`

```
private void F0118_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string RepPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\REP0100.rpt"; 

    ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument();
    rep.Load(RepPath);

    rep.SetParameterValue("P_PatientID", vPatientID);

    RepViewer.ReportSource = rep;
    rep.Refresh();
}
```

what I need to know is

1. is the parameter should be `static` or `dynamic` list of values?
2. do I have to set a default value for it ?
3. I do not want to display the prompt that asks for the parameter  value on run time
4. What I have to do to link that parameter to database fields I display on report so data in report are related to the `ID` entered by user in `form1` `textbox`?

finally there is no more code to show I post all codes I write for this the reset of things I made throw wizards there is n coding

please help and thanks alot